# Is it Fine to use ViewModel without Live Data

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-mvvm

I am using `LiveData` in `AndroidViewModel` class where i need to wait for the response, but there are some cases where i need to check some value from local `shared preference`, which won't block any thread.

For these scenarios i am not using `LiveData`. This is what i am doing in my `activity class`.

```
 homeViewModel.sendTokenToServer().observe(this, isFCMSendToServer -> {
        Toast.makeText(this, "FCM Token Observer called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 });


//Without Live Data

if(homeViewModel.isUpgradeAvailable()){
     displayAlertMessage();
}
```

I want to know if the above approach is fine, or we have to use `LiveData` or some other observers for each method in `ViewModel`

Comment: `LiveData` can be part of your Synchronous and Asynchronous call. No need to switch to the typical listener pattern.

Answer (score 11):

AFAIK `ViewModel` and `LiveData` are not tightly connected. Therefore you are not obliged to use any observers. For example in [this](https://medium.com/google-developers/viewmodels-a-simple-example-ed5ac416317e) sample app, the `ViewModel` is used to preserve some numbers through orientation change. Therefore `ViewModel` serves as a container (something like a headless fragment) where you can store data to be retained through orientation change.